# Modify loop but keep the original query, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: query-posts, loop

I have a custom post type where I have a taxonomy `cities` and a term `berlin`. Archive can be seen at `example.com/cities/berlin` and it's rendered normally from the `archive.php` template.

Now, I want to order them according to a custom field, `start_date` in this case, but still keep the original query around. So that when I navigate to `example.com/cities/newyork` the loop would still work as expected.

This is what I have but I only get the `<p>Not Found</p>` in the end.

Please help.

Thanks :)

```
<?php
global $query_string; //to keep the original query around
$args = array(
  'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
  'meta_key' => 'start_date',
  'order'    => 'DESC'
);
$posts = query_posts($query_string . $args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>

do stuff

<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p>Not Found</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't concatenate an array onto query_string like that. See [Digging Into WordPress's post about looping](http://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/#query-posts) for the right format. Alternately, you can use `array_merge()` like on the [query_posts Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Preserving_Existing_Query_Parameters).

Consider using `wp_reset_query()` after your loop. Sometimes you'll also see people save the original `$query_string` to a new variable, modify `$query_string`, and then reset `$query_string` after the loop like so:

```
global $query_string;
$old_query = $query_string
// Modify your query, loop through it
$query_string = $old_query;
```

Comment: @any_h if this solved your problem, make sure to accept it as the answer. Otherwise, update your question and explain why this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but it was on the front page, so it is my duty to post and say **"Don't ever use `query_posts()`"**  To modify the query without destroying the original query, you should use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook.

```
function wpa_49346_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if( is_tax() ){
        set_query_var( 'meta_key', 'start_date' );
        set_query_var( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        set_query_var( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_49346_pre_get_posts' );
```